# Shiny: display HTML table with CSS style applied by a JS function

Tags: r, shiny

I want to display an HTML table generated by the `tinytable` package in a Shiny app. One cell of the table has CSS styling applied by a JavaScript function triggered by a `window.addEventListener`.

What I have tried so far is:

1. Split the table component from the JS script component.
2. Supply the script to `ui` via the `tags@head(tags$script(HTML(script)))`
3. Supply the table to `server` via `renderUI(HTML(table))`

When I run the app, visit the website, and select View Source, I see the script in head, but the style does not get applied to the table.

This is the code I have used so far:

```r
library("shiny")
library("tinytable")

# Create a styled HTML table using the tinytable package
tab <- tt(mtcars[1:5, 1:4]) %>% 
  style_tt(1, 1, color = "orange", background = "black") %>% 
  save_tt("html") 

# Split script from table
lines <- strsplit(tab, "\n")[[1]]
idx_open <- max(grep("<script>$", lines))
idx_close <- max(grep("</script>$", lines))
script <- paste(lines[(idx_open + 1):(idx_close - 1)], collapse ="\n")
tab <- c(lines[1:(idx_open-1)], lines[(idx_close+1):length(lines)])
tab <- paste(tab, collapse = "\n")

# Launch Shiny app
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    tags$head(tags$script(HTML(script))),
    fluidRow(column(12, h1("This is test of tiny table"), uiOutput('table')))), 
  server = function(input, output) {n
    output$table <- renderUI(HTML(tab))
  }
)
```

The styled table should look like this:

[image]

In the Shiny app, the table appears nicely, but without the orange on black cell.

The full HTML is included below the fold for reference:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>tinytable_foso3jzxac6xevph2ijf</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
.table td.tinytable_css_c4k1sy9wnv7b3ohvpz8x, .table th.tinytable_css_c4k1sy9wnv7b3ohvpz8x {    border-bottom: solid 0.1em #d3d8dc; }
.table td.tinytable_css_301bqkqzpns14bb4286d, .table th.tinytable_css_301bqkqzpns14bb4286d {    color: orange; background-color: black; }
    </style>
    <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=es6"></script>
    <script id="MathJax-script" async src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js"></script>
    <script>
    MathJax = {
      tex: {
        inlineMath: [['$', '$'], ['\\(', '\\)']]
      },
      svg: {
        fontCache: 'global'
      }
    };
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <table class="table table-borderless" id="tinytable_foso3jzxac6xevph2ijf" style="width: auto; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" data-quarto-disable-processing='true'>
        <thead>
        
              <tr>
                <th scope="col">mpg</th>
                <th scope="col">cyl</th>
                <th scope="col">disp</th>
                <th scope="col">hp</th>
              </tr>
        </thead>
        
        <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td>21.0</td>
                  <td>6</td>
                  <td>160</td>
                  <td>110</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>21.0</td>
                  <td>6</td>
                  <td>160</td>
                  <td>110</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>22.8</td>
                  <td>4</td>
                  <td>108</td>
                  <td> 93</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>21.4</td>
                  <td>6</td>
                  <td>258</td>
                  <td>110</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>18.7</td>
                  <td>8</td>
                  <td>360</td>
                  <td>175</td>
                </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      function styleCell_tinytable_a3n06841ebx0qj2p20q5(i, j, css_id) {
        var table = document.getElementById("tinytable_foso3jzxac6xevph2ijf");
        table.rows[i].cells[j].classList.add(css_id);
      }
      function insertSpanRow(i, colspan, content) {
        var table = document.getElementById('tinytable_foso3jzxac6xevph2ijf');
        var newRow = table.insertRow(i);
        var newCell = newRow.insertCell(0);
        newCell.setAttribute("colspan", colspan);
        // newCell.innerText = content;
        // this may be unsafe, but innerText does not interpret <br>
        newCell.innerHTML = content;
      }
      function spanCell_tinytable_a3n06841ebx0qj2p20q5(i, j, rowspan, colspan) {
        var table = document.getElementById("tinytable_foso3jzxac6xevph2ijf");
        const targetRow = table.rows[i];
        const targetCell = targetRow.cells[j];
        for (let r = 0; r < rowspan; r++) {
          // Only start deleting cells to the right for the first row (r == 0)
          if (r === 0) {
            // Delete cells to the right of the target cell in the first row
            for (let c = colspan - 1; c > 0; c--) {
              if (table.rows[i + r].cells[j + c]) {
                table.rows[i + r].deleteCell(j + c);
              }
            }
          }
          // For rows below the first, delete starting from the target column
          if (r > 0) {
            for (let c = colspan - 1; c >= 0; c--) {
              if (table.rows[i + r] && table.rows[i + r].cells[j]) {
                table.rows[i + r].deleteCell(j);
              }
            }
          }
        }
        // Set rowspan and colspan of the target cell
        targetCell.rowSpan = rowspan;
        targetCell.colSpan = colspan;
      }

window.addEventListener('load', function () { styleCell_tinytable_a3n06841ebx0qj2p20q5(0, 0, 'tinytable_css_c4k1sy9wnv7b3ohvpz8x') })
window.addEventListener('load', function () { styleCell_tinytable_a3n06841ebx0qj2p20q5(0, 1, 'tinytable_css_c4k1sy9wnv7b3ohvpz8x') })
window.addEventListener('load', function () { styleCell_tinytable_a3n06841ebx0qj2p20q5(0, 2, 'tinytable_css_c4k1sy9wnv7b3ohvpz8x') })
window.addEventListener('load', function () { styleCell_tinytable_a3n06841ebx0qj2p20q5(0, 3, 'tinytable_css_c4k1sy9wnv7b3ohvpz8x') })
window.addEventListener('load', function () { styleCell_tinytable_a3n06841ebx0qj2p20q5(1, 0, 'tinytable_css_301bqkqzpns14bb4286d') })
    </script>

  </body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you simply want to bake the table as a html, and insert it into shiny; the most trivial way is :

```
library("shiny")
library("tinytable")

# Create a styled HTML table using the tinytable package
tab <- tt(mtcars[1:5, 1:4]) |> 
  style_tt(1, 1, color = "orange", background = "black") |> 
  save_tt("html") 

 writeLines(tab,"tt_test.html")

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    fluidRow(column(12, h1("This is test of tiny table"), 
                    shiny::includeHTML("tt_test.html")))), 
  server = function(input, output) { 
  }
)
```